# Chinese keyboard and Secure Text Entry

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I am updating one of my apps to localize to 7 other languages besides English. Chinese, Traditional is one of the languages.

Am performing the final tests before submission.

Scenario: user creates a Username, Password and Email from three UITextField spaces.
The username field, and email field show the Chinese keyboard that allows the user to "draw" the characters.

Everything works fine, with the exception of a password entry field.
It is merely a UITextField, created from the Storyboard. Use auto layout.
Have no issues with any other languages.

The only difference between the text fields is Secure Text Entry is selected, duh, for the password field. On the device when testing, all of the languages display from the "globe" and I can cycle through them... except Chinese!

My question: does iOS not allow a Chinese "drawing" keyboard when Secure Text Entry is selected? I can't find any entries on this topic.

Thanks for any assistance. I've attached a screen capture of the Password field attributes.

[image: The image below shows the selected options for the Password textfield.]